# Why Am I getting Canvas: trying to draw too large bitmap android error

Tags: android-camera, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-developer-api

I have an android app with a fragment with one imagebutton, another button and one imageview to take a photo using camera device but in Galaxy A33 I'm getting this error
java.lang.RuntimeException - Canvas: trying to draw too large(256576512bytes) bitmap.
android.graphics.RecordingCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw (RecordingCanvas.java:266)

To show photo I use this code taken from android docs

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO) && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          

            if (archivofoto!=null&&archivofoto.exists()) {
                if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO) {
                   
                    if(ComprasUtils.getAvailableMemory(getActivity()).lowMemory)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No hay memoria suficiente para esta accion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        return;
                    }else {
                       
                       ComprasUtils cu = new ComprasUtils();
                        cu.comprimirImagen(archivofoto.getAbsolutePath());
                        Bitmap bitmap1 = ComprasUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(archivofoto.getAbsolutePath(), 100, 100);
                      
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                       
                        imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 
                        nombre_foto=null;
                        archivofoto=null;
                    }

                }


            }
            else{
                Log.e(TAG,"Algo salió mal???");
            }


       }
          else
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"Algo salió muy mal**");
        }
    }
```

decodeSampledBitmapFromResource function supposed to compress photo to show it but  error give me the idea that is not working or what am I doing wrong?

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource( String nombre_foto,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        File archivo = new File(nombre_foto);
        if (!archivo.exists()) {
            return null;
        }
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
       // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(nombre_foto,options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile( nombre_foto, options);
    }
```